# Outbound email TBB not uploaded in CMS 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013-sp1, templating, outbound-email

We setup AudienceManager and Outbound email in our CMS 2013 SP1. But can't see the default outbound e-mail TBB in CMS anywhere. Now CMS is running and we have contacts and outbound email in use. We wanted to use the Outbound TBB to implement tracking. What are the steps to upload these TBBs into CMS server?

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Template Builder
2. Click the Tools menu and select Create Default Building Blocks
3. Select the **parent** folder to your Default Templates folder (i.e. if your default templates are currently in Building Blocks\Templates\Default Templates, pick Building Blocks\Templates).

That's it. It will update your default templates, including the Outbound E-mail TBBs.

Comment: Peter the issue is that I can't find the outbound email TBBs. I think it was not uploaded into CMS server during installation. Ok, what we did was follow this link https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/outbound_email_templating.aspx

Comment: Did you try the steps I gave? They get uploaded as part of the Default Templates nowadays...